# Проблемы с getline

Tags: c++, getline

Моя задача: получение строк по номеру из файла. Если текст, который мне нужен на латинице, то нет проблем, а если на кириллице - получаю каракули.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал менять кодировки/шрифт консоли.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

// <...>

string readFile(int n){
    ifstream f(readpath);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        getline(f, s);
    }
    f.close();
    return(s);
}

int main(){
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    cout << readFile(1) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Файл: [image: кодировка]

Comment: Ну так Вы сами принудительно выставляете кодировку 1251.

Comment: В языковых настройках windows (административные языковые настройки) можно включить экспериментальную поддержку utf8. После этого консоль сможет читать и писать utf8 строки. SetConsoleCP в этом случае, естественно, не нужен. Недостаток:  некоторые приложения будут показывать знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы. Из современных, на данный момент мне известно только одно такое, и это ошибка его разработчиков.